# How to automatically convert cucumber .feature file to .py file using .bat file

Tags: python-3.x, cucumber

I want to convert my .feature file to .py step definition that is the python file.

I have created a cucumber folder in mt eclipse. I need to convert this feature file using .bat file

```
Feature: Google Homepage
This feature verifies the functionality on Google Homepage

Scenario: Check that main elements on Google Homepage are displayed
Given I launch Chrome browser
When I open Google Homepage
Then I verify that the page displays search text box
And the page displays Google Search button
And the page displays Im Feeling Lucky button
```

Comment: I'm actually not seeing a way to stub step definitions in mass for Python using the command line. A related question: [How to write cucumber Step definitions in python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31317773/3092298).

Comment: I saw the above mentioned answer, but I don't know how to use java and jython. I don't think this will be helpful, because I need a .py file directly created in Eclipse.