# Python unable to pass parameters from feature file to step definition in cucumber

Tags: python, selenium, automation, cucumber, python-behave

I am trying to implement POM pattern in selenium with cucumber using python. When I am trying to do pass parameters from cucumber feature file to step definition getting blocked.  I have already searched on stack over flow ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31317773/how-to-write-cucumber-step-definitions-in-python)) but solutions didn't help me much.

Please find my work and help me in resolving or redirect me to any resources, where can I find support..

Here is my feature file and trying to pass parameters

[image]

And below is my step definitions implementation, 
[image]

Trying to debug and no luck. Also note that I am trying to execute test using python-behave and from pycharm running directly from feature file.

Solutions I have tried and not worked:

1:
from feature file: `launch the application 'url_address'`
in step def file: `@given('launch the application {url} ')`

2:
from feature file: `launch the application 'url_address'`
in step def file: `@given('launch the application "{url}" ')`

3:
from feature file: `launch the application '<url_address>'`
in step def file: `@given('launch the application "{url}"')`

4:
from feature file: `launch the application '<url_address>'`
in step def file: `@given('launch the application "(.*)" ')`

Thank you in advance

Comment: Please do not post images of code. It is difficult to read.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you use your quotes inconsistently for parameters in your step_definition.

If you use single quotes for parameters in your step_definition, you need to do so as well in the feature file.

You have to following (different) step_definitions:

```
@given('Launch the application "(.*)"')

@then("Click on '(.*)' image")
```

You should pick one way of doing this. Both are fine, but if you want to keep it this you need to call them in 2 different ways in your feature file as well.

---

***QUICKFIX***

The (.feature) example below should work with how your step_definitions are as show in your screenshot:

*(Double quotes define in step_definition, so use double quotes for paramter in feater)*

```
Given Launch the applicaion "https://www.whateverurl.com"
```

*(Single quotes defined in step_definition, so use single quotes for parameter in feature)*

```
Then Click on 'imageName' image
```

**SUGGESTION:**
Use single quotes in your step_definitions for the step name and use double quotes for parameters (like you have done in 'Launche the application' step). Just keep ik mind to call paramters in double quotes then.

please let me know if this was of any help!

Comment: I don't think that could be the problem. Sorry friend your solution is not working

Comment: That's a shame. I ran into this very similar problem and looking at your code it looked like you where experiencing the same thing. 

Have you tried losing the brackets in your .feature when you pass the URL as parameter? In your screenshot you have put your url within brackets.

Comment: Also i see that with the working steps you use a unicode string. Perhaps you can try that as well with your 'launch the application "" ' step?

Answer (score 0):

Behave supports multiple **step matchers** to match parameters in steps.
The default matcher is the **parse** matcher.
Therefore, your step definitions should look like:

```py
# -- FILE: features/steps/browser_steps.py
...
@given('launch the application "{url}"')
def step_given_launch_application(context, url):
    print("Using url={0}".format(url))
```

```
# -- FILE: features/example.feature
Feature:

  Scenario: 
    Given launch the application "https://example.com"
```

HINTS:

- In the description above you have a trailing whitespace: 'launch ... {url} '.
  This can cause problems, because this whitespace is probably not matched when the feature file is parsed. The parser strips whitespace at the end of each line.
- Double-quotes versus single-quotes is not the same. 
  Use the same both in Gherkin and step definition.
- Upper-case versus lower-case: Step matching is case sensitive
  You are using "Given Launch application ..." in Gherkin but are using "launch application ..." in step definition in Python
- If you want to use the Regular Expression step matcher, you should use named-parameters (behave cannot guess what you mean, you must specify it correctly)

SEE ALSO:

- [behave.example Github repository](https://github.com/behave/behave.example)
- [behave.example docs: Using Step Matchers](http://behave.github.io/behave.example/step_matcher/index.html)
- [behave.example docs: Using Parse Matcher](http://behave.github.io/behave.example/step_matcher/parse_matcher.html)
- [behave.example docs: Using Regular Expression Matcher](http://behave.github.io/behave.example/step_matcher/re_matcher.html)